# CSS transform Scale translates the object, how to avoid this?

Tags: css, svg, transform, scale

I want to scale an object as an animation, I want it to stay in position and just grow, but when programming this, the whole drawing grows, even though I just applied the code to the circle in this example: http://codepen.io/Filipo/pen/JYVvXK

```
<svg>
<g transform="translate(0 -662.36)">
<circle id="dedo" r="35" style="color-rendering:auto;color:#000000;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;fill-rule:evenodd;shape-rendering:auto;solid-color:#000000;image-rendering:auto;fill:#fff" cx="147.62" cy="741.74"/>
</g>
</svg>

body {background-color: black;}
#dedo{
animation: deslizando 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes deslizando {
0% {opacity: 1;}
100% {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}
```

It's a rectangular SVG with a circle inside of it, when I grow the circle, it changes it's location, I want it to stay in it's original location.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply an origin to the scale, it defaults to the top-left, sounds like you probably want it in the middle

```
#dedo{
  animation: deslizando 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I just applied the code to the codepen link and still doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect you may need [vendor prefixes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp). Most [modern browsers support unprefixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), but not all.

Comment: Matt Styles is right! but I have to apply the effect not to the circle, but to the whole drawing. Thanks Matt